# Mono hangs when called from a CGI script

Tags: c#, bash, mono, cross-platform, cgi

I have a program written in C# which I need to call from a CGI script.

When I call the program from either a python or bash CGI script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Content-type: text/plain
echo
echo    
/home/<user>/.mono/bin/mono HelloWorld.exe
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess

print 'Content-type: text/plain\n\n'
p=subprocess.Popen(['/home/<user>/.mono/bin/mono','HelloWorld.exe'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print p.stdout.read().strip('\r\n')
```

the process hangs and the browser waits indefinitely for a response. As you will have noticed I have mono "installed" in my home directory as I don't have root privileges. It was compiled on the server and the executable is just sitting in that directory, but it seems to work fine for everything else.

**What makes the problem confusing is:**

- The problem doesn't occur if I call the command or indeed the cgi script myself eg. from an SSH session.
- The problem seems to occur after the program has run: if I pipe the results to a file the results appear in the file file, mono just seems to hang after it's finished.
- The problem doesn't occur on my mac laptop with the same cgi script and .exe but with mono properly installed.
- The problem doesn't occur if the script just calls mono eg. (`subprocess.Popen(['/home/<user>/.mono/bin/mono'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`) - mono just prints the standard "you've given me nothing to do" message and exits normally.
- The problem occurs with any .exe whether it is just hello world or making some relatively complex calculations, which is what my actual program does.

I've tried setting `MONO_SHARED_DIR` to a directory that is world writable as I originally thought this was the same problem as that seen with fake-root see [the Mono FAQ page](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ%3a_Technical).

`gdb` gives the following output:

```
Loaded symbols for /lib/libpthread.so.0
Reading symbols from /lib/libc.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libc.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib/libnss_compat.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libnss_compat.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib/libnsl.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libnsl.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib/libnss_nis.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libnss_nis.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib/libnss_files.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libnss_files.so.2
0x00007f85d7680b50 in sem_wait () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
```

I've googled the last line and `sem_wait` but I can't find anything relevant as this seems to be a common problem.

Any help on this problem would be very much appreciated, I really don't want to rewrite my whole program in C++ from C#.

Version information:

- OS: Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS
- Mono: Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.2 (tarball Sat Jun 18 15:11:20 BST 2011)
- Apache: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)

Comment: Do you really get this hanging mono process when you pipe the output to a flat file? If yes, then something is very wrong with your mono install.

Comment: Yes, I get the exact same response with: /home/<user>/.mono/bin/mono HelloWorld.exe >> outputfile I'm sure there is something wrong with my mono installation, but I would love to know what and how to fix it.

Comment: really really strange, I've had this only when i've pinvoked into things that create native threads, never plain managed code.  Id try and build mono from source if I were in your boat.

Comment: I did build Mono from source. Moreover, yesterday I downloaded the most recent Mono tarball (mono-20110609) and compiled that, compilation went without a hitch but I got the exact same problem. It's driving me round the bend.

Comment: `man sem_wait` if you want to know what that is. Try `exec`ing mono. `exec /home/<user>/.mono/bin/mono HelloWorld.exe`

Comment: does mono, or your application, require any environment variables? Sounds like it could be an environment issue.

Comment: humm, I'm afraid I don't remember, it was some time ago. I ended up rewriting the code in Javascript. I don't think there were any environment variables, I remember being pleasantly surprised at how easy compiling and running mono was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer probably isn't interesting to most people, but for completeness I should provide it.

Retrosnub who run the server I was using have a separate web server and ssh server. I had obviously compiled mono on the ssh server, but when I tried calling it from a CGI script it was being executed by the web server. The web server has a different architecture (32bit not 64bit) which caused all the problems.